# Eclipse wrong formatter spacing

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Since I did Right Mouse > Source > Format on one of my projects, all my files in Eclipse are formatted wrong. They use spaces and only two of them:

```
public class XYZ {
  public XYZ( ) {
    ;
  }
}
```

But in my formatter, settings I set it to "only use tabs" and a tab size of 4! But it doesn't work? What can I do now?
It should look like this:

```
public class XYZ {
    public XYZ( ) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Here is how my formatter settings looks like.
[image: Formatter Settings]
And here how the code really gets formatted. Without tabs and an indention of only 2 spaces!
[image: How The Files Really Look]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've selected the correct "Active Profile" to use on *Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter*.

**EDIT**: Another possibility would be to use a "Clean Up Profile" instead. Try creating one and set those ticks. [image: Clean Up Profile editing window]

Then do *Right Mouse > Source > Clean Up...*, select your created profile and run the Clean Up. [image: "Clean Up..." window]

Comment: I did. Added some screenshots.